# My Nginx service is running and if I run curl localhost it shows landing page HTML. But cannot access from ec2 IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-config

When I ping my localhost or ip 127.0.0.1 it returns nginx landing page html. But from my public IP I cannot access it. I reinstalled nginx. But issue didn't solved

ubuntu@ip-my-ip:~$ curl 127.0.0.1

````
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
        <style>
            body {
                width: 35em;
                margin: 0 auto;
                font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
        <p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
        working. Further configuration is required.</p>
        
        <p>For online documentation and support please refer to
        <a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
        Commercial support is available at
        <a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>
        
        <p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
        </body>
        </html>```
````

Comment: Does the security group attached to the instance allow traffic for the required ports?

Comment: Are you asking about `sudo ufw status` list? yes I allowed port. I also allowed port 5000 which is working perfectly. But port 80 doesn't work

Comment: Check port 80 on Security Group and open it if it's not and access your EC2 public Ip with http and not https like http://<yourpublicip>. Also , is your EC2 in public subnet(attached to IGW)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Inbound Rules for the Security Group that your Ec2 instance belongs.

By default when launching an Ec2 instance the Inbound SSH traffic is allowed from everywhere, but the HTTP and HTTPS are not:

[image]

To edit the configuration after lunch the instance:

- In AWS EC2 -> Go to  Instance and find your instance Security Group Name.
- Sill in AWS EC2 -> scroll the left panel until the Security Group in "Network & Security" -> Find the Security Group that your EC2 instance belongs to and edit the Inbound rules to allow HTTP (Port 80) and HTTPS (Port 443) from your IP or any IP.

Comment: Thanks, I already solved this yesterday. The solution was same.

Comment: You saved my day bro, this happened with me on Alibaba Cloud.
Thanks